# Why won't my data from my database be displayed to the front end using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, frontend, flask-sqlalchemy, backend

First time user with flask. I am trying to build a simple blog style website where I compose a post, proceed to submit that post, and then display that post.

Other than not displaying to the front end, my database (named BlogPost) appears to be working as it should. For example, I am able to query data from the database, so data is indeed being stored correctly. I am using sqlite as my database. Everything regarding my app (CSS styling, database storage, form submission) is working correctly, the only issue is displaying the data to `/posts`.  If more information is required for an effective answer, please just comment below.

P.S.
'author' is populated with my name
[image: Here is my current file setup]
[image: Here is my attempt to display data from my databse(BlogPost) to webpage]

Comment: Try to use logger and log all_posts before returning it. you will get an idea about data is getting from database or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Jinja templating in your HTML.

`posts.html`

```
{{posts}}
```

You will probably want to show information from each post, so you might try something like the following (with your styling added)

`posts.html`

```
{% for post in posts %}

{{post.title}}
{{post.author}}
{{post.content}}

{% endfor %}
```

More information on Jinja templating can be found [on the Jinja documentation page.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Jinja syntax on posts.html simply adding {{ all_posts }} somewhere in the body should do the trick.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on what that syntax might look like? Is it simply what you shared (  {{ all_posts }} ), or do I need a for loop to iterate through {{ all_posts }}?

Comment: you may need a for loop. something simple might work like {% for item in all_posts %} and then you would use {{ items }}. Then you would need an {% endfor %} at the below {{ items }}.